# manifests or manifests itself

Tags: formality, science, academia, academic-writing

The sentence (from University Physics book, the image of full text is attached):

> The work done by nonconservative forces **manifests itself** as changes in the
> internal energy of objects.

Can we delete the word **itself**, if we do, which way is more adopted in math academic writing ?

> The work done by nonconservative forces **manifests** as changes in the
> internal energy of objects.

We have above use in the following sentence of medicine:

> ‘a disorder that usually **manifests** in middle age’ ([an example of non transitive verb use from the Oxford Dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/manifest))

[image]

Comment: When "as" is involved, I feel like I usually see "manifests itself as" - but "manifests as" sounds unobjectionable to me, and, actually, yep, I like it better.  Compare the word "presents," which, when used in a reflexive sense, almost always gets "itself," but doesn't necessarily need it (and often doesn't get it in a medical context).

Comment: While both are grammatically correct, the "itself" stresses or highlights the comparison between conservative force & nonconservative force. Previous Sentence talks about Work by conservative force having a Potential Energy function; Current Sentence highlights that Work by nonconservative force (having no Potential Energy function) "manifests **itself**" in Internal Energy .... Both are grammatically correct, but "itself" is better ....

Comment: Adding "itself" is an anthropomorphism that suggests that the work *causes* the changes, rather than it being something something that occurs spontaneously.

Comment: I'd say 'manifests itself' is high (formal) register, 'manifests' is rarefied.